# "Gallifrey Falls No More" - a way to bring back timelords?

Tags: doctor-who

When the Doctors were in the painting, when they unfroze, everything else came alive and actually exists, as proven when the Dalek said "exterminate" and crashed through the painting. Since the painting still exists, can't the Doctor go back in and rescue a few living Timelords?

Comment: This question makes my brain hurt.

Comment: Wibbely-wobbely, timey-wimey. Can do if the plot requires so. ;-)

Comment: Am I misremembering the episode? I thought it was pretty much said that the time lords are saved, merely hidden, and that the doctor even goes and searches for gallifrey now that he knows its there (not blown up)?

Comment: @MacCooper Yes, but the question is whether or not the Doctor can go into the painting and pull other Time Lords out, from within the painting.

Comment: @Dave Johnson, ah as an alternative, I get you. Huh, brain must have turned off because yknow that doesn't take a genius to figure out :/

Comment: I always thought that's how The Master escaped Gallifrey and the Time War. Check out the frame where Clara goes out of the painting. I don't think that's her hand.

Comment: @tilley31 Except that would mean that the Master was already Missy before the end of the Time War when we already know that by then he was hiding out at Utopia as Professor Yana. EDIT: Well, no, I take that back. Because of the events of The End of Time, there would effectively have been TWO versions of the Master at that time -- Professor Yana and the John Simm version sucked back through by Rassilon. Guess we'll have to wait until Season 9 to know for sure!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the Doctors used the same technology that the Zygons used to insert themselves into the already existing painting, giving them a freedom of movement that anyone else in the painting wouldn't have.

The painting isn't a window into another time like, say, the portals on the SS Madame du Pompadour. It's not something that people as a rule can just pop in and out of at will. It's a frozen moment in time, but it's still just a copy of that frozen moment. Photorealism taken to the extreme.

Imagine painting a picture on the inside of a box. You could get in the box after you're done, have the box taken somewhere, and then get out of the box, but anything that's painted on the inside of the box is still just a painting; you can't take it out with you.

Or, rather, you could, with a pair of scissors (or a set of sonic screwdrivers), but what you came out with would still be a copy and probably wouldn't survive. It wasn't the sonics that killed that Dalek, it was being ripped from the painting.